# How to download multiple sequences in one fasta file from UniProt using Python 3

Tags: python, python-requests, append, fasta

I made a python script for downloading protein sequences from Uniprot in fasta format. The script will read the accession numbers from a text file containing the accession numbers (one on each line) and then try to download the respective sequence from UniProt database. Here is the script:

```
import requests

with open ('testfasta.txt', 'r') as infile:
    lines = infile.readlines()
count = 0
for line in lines:
    count+=1
    line = line.strip()
    access_id = line
    url_part1 = 'https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/'
    url_part2 = '.fasta'

    URL = url_part1+access_id+url_part2
              
    response = requests.get (URL)
              
    with open((access_id)+".fa", "wb") as txtFile:
        txtFile.write(response.content)

print ("Total sequences downloaded = ", count)
```

This works fine but for hundreds of sequences, it will generate a large number of files. So, it is beneficial to have the next incoming sequence written below the first one, then second one after it and so on. A fasta file format is basically a text file containing text with its header marked with ">".
e.g.

```
>firstseq_header
djsfkasdjfkasjdfkasjdflkasjdflkasjdfkasdjfsadk
iewurpwierpofasiodfjlkasdfklasjowieqrudsafdsaf
>secseq_header
dsfjsdfkjasfasdfhwrwerewrasdfasrwerasdfa
awerwerasafas
>nseq_header
ajskdfhjasdfhlasjdhfwueroywieuhsjadfh
hdsfkjh
```

and so on

Comment: We can't know what's in your text file, so this isn't really a [mre]. I tested my answer with `infile = ["P06213", "P14735", "P01308"]` based on an example on the web site.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sorry for being unclear. The text file is a list of accession IDs (with each accession ID written on one line). The script reads and fetches the respective fasta sequence from Uniprot. In the meantime, I partially solved the problem by using .append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Just write them all to the same file.

```
import requests

with open('testfasta.txt', 'r') as infile,
     open('results.fasta', 'w') as outfile:
  for count, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
    access_id = line.strip()              
    response = requests.get(
      f'https://rest.uniprot.org/uniprotkb/{access_id}.fasta')
    # check that fetch succeeded; raise error if not
    response.raise_for_status()
    assert(response.text.startswith('>'))
    assert(response.text.endswith('\n'))
    outfile.write(response.text)

print (f"Total sequences downloaded = {count}")
```

This assumes that the data you fetch is newline-terminated, and includes the FASTA header before the sequence itself. If that's not necessarily always true, maybe replace the `assert`s with code to fix any such problems. I also made various changes to make it more idiomatic.

A vague complication is that the `response.content` you download is not text, but `bytes`. You could `decode` it if you wanted to, but of course, Requests already does this for you, and provides that in `response.text`

Comment: The sequence download works. Next, I would like to print a notice that if I put a wrong ID and it doesn't fetch a proper sequence. I will try that and if it doesn't work, I'll make a new post.

Comment: (This already generates a traceback if you put an invalid ID which causes the fetch to fail.)

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, it does give the error when I put an invalid ID. So far, I haven't figured out how to count such instances, and get a correct count of how many sequences downloaded and how many unsuccessful with their respective IDs, so I know which ones I need to find elsewhere.

Comment: Then don't raise an exception, just add the failed one to a list, and then print the list of failed IDs to the terminal or save it to a file. In brief, if the return code in the response is 4xx or 5xx, it failed. See also e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463224/when-to-use-raise-for-status-vs-status-code-testing